# DieHarder, get p-value column

Tags: linux, random, cryptography, statistics

I perform the DieHarder tests on my RNG, and I would like to plot the resulting p-values.
([Just like this guy does](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/2d4m1v/how_random_is_your_data_on_interpreting_diehard/)).
So, I don't need the final p-value of a single test, but the whole range of p-values (0,1] for each test.

I was able to extract the p-values for the first test of DieHard, by using verbose mode `-v 1`.
At the end of the output, there was a column with 100 sorted p-values.
I think this is what I want to plot.

However, I am not able to use `-v 1` with the other tests. They just generate to much output (GigaBytes!), it crashes my computer.

The question is: How can I extract the 100 sorted p-values column, without using `-v 1`?

Thank You.

I run DieHarder on a Desktop Ubuntu which has it installed by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get the p-values with DieHard**er**.

But, using the original DIEHARD gave all the p-values.